# Running Mongodb community on Mac with platform linux/amd

Tags: linux, mongodb, docker

I am trying to run a mongodb container with `--platform linux/amd` on a Mac M2;

Command:

```
docker run --name mongodb -d -p 27017:27017 mongodb/mongodb-community-server:latest
```

I get the following error:

```
2023-12-07 08:57:50 Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-12-07 08:57:50   File "/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.py", line 637, in <module>
2023-12-07 08:57:50     subprocess.run(get_final_command_line_args(), check=True)
2023-12-07 08:57:50   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 526, in run
2023-12-07 08:57:50     raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
2023-12-07 08:57:50 subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['mongod', '--bind_ip_all']' died with <Signals.SIGILL: 4>.
```

I have no problem running other `linux/amd` docker container sand the `arm` version of this docker image works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `--platform linux/arm64` instead of `--platform linux/amd`:

```
docker run --name mongodb -d -p 27017:27017 --platform linux/arm64 mongodb/mongodb-community-server:latest
```